# How do I hide notifications about running tasks?

Tags: tasks, plugin-import

I installed Import.  I tried to run a test import and it froze.   Now the pop-up status that appears in Craft's menu - just below Settings - will not disappear.

I even uninstalled the plugin.  But, the status notification is still in the menu.   It's driving me nuts.

[image]

*How do I get rid of it?*   At this point, I don't care about getting import to work or not.

(Oh, and there were no image transforms with the test import - it was only 21 lines of a simple css file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are running tasks that Craft (and plugins) use to perform long running maintenance operations and an Import task got [stuck](https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks) causing the ones to come after it not to run.

Since you don't care about the Import task anymore, you can open the `craft_tasks` table in the database and delete the one for the Import task (probably the top row).  The next time you load the control panel, the remaining tasks should complete.

Comment: You can also grab the [Task Manager](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/taskmanager) plugin, which allows you to kill tasks without editing the database directly.